# Insert into MySQL is not working and there're no errors

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

I'm trying to insert products information into the database, but I must be missing something. It does not insert anything into the database, it's not even showing any errors.

Whats wrong with my code?

```
<?php 

    if(!empty($product_name)){
        if(!empty($product_category)){

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///// connect to database
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        $dbc = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "table");

        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbc)) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }

        if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

            $pid = ($_POST['thisID']);
            $product_name = ($_POST['product_name']);
            $product_category = ($_POST['product_category']);
            $product_detail = ($_POST['product_detail']);
            $product_price = ($_POST['product_price']);
            $product_company = ($_POST['product_company']);

            $query = "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_category, product_price, product_detail,product_detail, product_company)
                VALUES ( '$product_name','$product_category','$product_price','$product_detail','$product_company')";

            $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");

            if($result){
                header('location:cp_product.php');
            }

            mysqli_close($dbc);
        }
    }}

?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: How do you know there are no errors if you don't print `$mysqli->error` when the query fails?

Comment: Shouldn't `$this->mysqli->query` be `$dbc->query`?

Answer (score 2):

In your query you have add the `product_detail` column two times,there should be one ,as five columns refers to 5 values

```
product_detail,product_detail,

INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_category, product_price, product_detail, product_company)
VALUES ( '$product_name','$product_category','$product_price','$product_detail','$product_company');
```

Answer (score 0):

`product_detail` twice in insert query

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
    $result= $this->mysqli->query($query) or die(mysqli_connect_errno()."Data cannot inserted");
```

It should be:

```
    $result = $dbc->query($query) or die ($dbc->error . "Data cannot be inserted");
```

If you'd done this, you would have gotten the error that the column list doesn't match the `VALUES` list, because you put `product_detail` in the column list twice.

Answer (score 0):

i see that you called your database "table".
Is your database called "table" ?
First Try this and tell us what errors your get:
Do not mix procdeural code with obejct oriented code. Check php.net examples.
(Remove all "ifs" for now.)
     
         $dbc = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "table");

```
 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 $pid = ($_POST['thisID']);
 $product_name = ($_POST['product_name']);
 $product_category = ($_POST['product_category']);
 $product_detail = ($_POST['product_detail']);
 $product_price = ($_POST['product_price']);
 $product_company = ($_POST['product_company']);

 $query = "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_category, product_price, product_detail, product_company)  
  VALUES (   '$product_name','$product_category','$product_price','$product_detail','$product_company')";   

  echo "query: ".$query."<br>";
  mysqli->query($query);

  $mysqli->close(); //object oriented.
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your DB connection, in this case $dbc, inside of the HTML form variables you're setting.

```
$pid = ($dbc, $_POST['thisID']);
$product_name = ($dbc, $_POST['product_name']);
$product_category = ($dbc, $_POST['product_category']);
$product_detail = ($dbc, $_POST['product_detail']);
$product_price = ($dbc, $_POST['product_price']);
$product_company = ($dbc,$_POST['product_company']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nobody said that ! how do you pass your query through your connection ?

You should have something like

```
$dbc->query( $query )
```

Or in your case where do you assign `$this->mysqli` ?

Don't mix Object Oriented style with Procedural style as this may cause you confusion in the future.

Choose one and continue coding in that style. If you can choose OOP.

GOOD LUCK